# Webpack integration in Angular2 App

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to use `Webpack` in my `Angular2`  app. 
However, I keep getting this error:

```
decorators.js:164 Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
```

Below is the folder structure.

```
 .
    ├── db.json
    ├── index.html
    ├── karma.conf.js
    ├── karma-test-shim.js
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── listing.md
    ├── package.json
    ├── README.md
    ├── src
    │   ├── app.component.ts
    │   ├── assets
    │   │   └── stylesheets
    │   │       └── style.css
    │   ├── components
    │   │   ├── employee-detail.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-detail.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-edit-form.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-edit-form.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-form.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-form.component.ts
    │   │   ├── list.component.spec.ts
    │   │   └── list.component.ts
    │   ├── main.ts
    │   ├── models
    │   │   ├── employee.spec.ts
    │   │   └── employee.ts
    │   ├── pages
    │   │   ├── app.component.html
    │   │   ├── employee-detail.component.html
    │   │   ├── employee-edit-form.component.html
    │   │   ├── employee-form.component.html
    │   │   └── employee-list.component.html
    │   ├── services
    │   │   ├── employee-delete-service.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-delete-service.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-detail-service.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-detail-service.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-edit-form-service.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-form-service.component.spec.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-form-service.component.ts
    │   │   ├── employee-list-service.component.spec.ts
    │   │   └── employee-list-service.component.ts
    │   └── tsconfig.json
    ├── typings
    │   ├── browser
    │   │   └── ambient
    │   │       ├── es6-shim
    │   │       │   └── es6-shim.d.ts
    │   │       └── jasmine
    │   │           └── jasmine.d.ts
    │   ├── browser.d.ts
    │   ├── main
    │   │   └── ambient
    │   │       ├── es6-shim
    │   │       │   └── es6-shim.d.ts
    │   │       └── jasmine
    │   │           └── jasmine.d.ts
    │   └── main.d.ts
    ├── typings.json
    └── webpack.config.js
```

And below is the `webpack.config.js` file

```
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "app": "./src/main"
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      { test: /\.html$/,  loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

I am new to `Webpack` and `Angular2`. Can anyone please tell me what configuration have I got wrong?

**Progress**

When I add following tags in the index.html, everything run fine.

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular requires some features that are not yet implemented in the browsers and therefore need to be polyfilled (which means adding an implementation for a not yet existing feature). So angular will only run if this code is available, which happens when you just add the scripts.

You can avoid adding the scripts manually by just importing the required shim and polyfill library in one of your bootstrap ts files (e.g. main.ts) or by simply defining a second webpack entrypoint (e.g. polyfills.ts) with these two imports:

```
import 'es6-shim/es6-shim';
import 'angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills';
```